# Problem with dimensions in Pytorch Autoencoder

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I am designing an autoencoder model. Here, the input blocks look alright.

```python
import os
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn.functional as F
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms, utils
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import cv2

from google.colab import drive
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

%matplotlib inline

os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"

#import a file from google drive
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
!ls "/content/drive/My Drive/summercourse/d7/pca_poker_data//"
root_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/summercourse/d7/'
root_ds = '/content/drive/My Drive/summercourse/d7/pca_poker_data/' #run this line in the colab IDE/environment
root_ds = './pca_poker_data/' #run this line in the jupyter/spyder IDE, and after you have downloaded my dataset
```

The code above was the libraries and the import directory. The block below is the input section

```python
class PokerDataset(Dataset): 
    def __init__(self,root,train,transform): 
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_files = []
        if train:
            dic = 'training'
        else:
            dic = 'testing'
        for label in os.listdir(root+dic): 
            for r, _, f in os.walk(root+dic+'/'+label):
                for item in range(len(f)):
                    self.image_files.append((r+'/'+f[item],int(label)))

    def __getitem__(self, index):    
        img_name, label = self.image_files[index]
        img = mpimg.imread(img_name)
        img = transforms.ToTensor()(np.array(img))
        return[img,label]

    def __len__(self): 
        return len(self.image_files)
    
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
img,label = PokerDataset(root_ds,True,transform).__getitem__(0)

print(type(img))
print(np.shape(img))
tempimg = np.zeros((96,71))
for i in range (96):
    for j in range (71):
        tempimg[i,j] = img[0,i,j]
        
#OUTPUT
#<class 'torch.Tensor'>
#torch.Size([1, 96, 71])

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(tempimg)
batchSize=13

#OUTPUT: Prints a card image

trainset = PokerDataset(root_ds,train=True,transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batchSize,
                                          shuffle=True)

testset = PokerDataset(root_ds,train=False,transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batchSize,
                                         shuffle=True)
                                         
classes = ('0', '1', '2', '3')

def show_batch(data):
    imgs = data[0]
    grid = utils.make_grid(imgs,nrow=batchSize)
#     print(grid.numpy().shape)
#     print(grid.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0)).shape)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(grid.numpy().transpose((1, 2, 0)))
    plt.title('')

for i, data in enumerate(testloader):
    if(i<4):
        show_batch(data)
    else:
        break
        
#OUTPUT: Prints 4 card batches of 13
```

As you can see, the input image dimension is 3 with the size of [1, 96, 71], how can I turn it to 4D? As the model needs a 4D tensor input.  And I expect the output like this

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIxy.png)

Whose link is here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18MbnVs6s4ncqkz7yQTN-rEznfkvq0BAX?usp=sharing

But when it comes to my model, the architecture and the parameters seem to be OK. But when I try to train a model, I suffered a dimensional issue of the input and the output tensors, they did not match:

```python
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential( # like the Composition layer you built
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 7)
        )
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, 7),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 1, 3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

net = Net()

def train(model, num_epochs=5, batch_size=13, learning_rate=1e-3):
    torch.manual_seed(9)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # mean square error loss
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),
                                 lr=learning_rate, 
                                 weight_decay=1e-5) # <--

    trainset = PokerDataset(root_ds,train=True,transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batchSize,
                                          shuffle=True)

    outputs = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for data in trainloader:
            img, _ = data
            recon = model(img)
            loss = criterion(recon, img) #the error was detected here
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

        print('Epoch:{}, Loss:{:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, float(loss)))
        outputs.append((epoch, img, recon),)
    return outputs

model = Autoencoder()
max_epochs = 20
outputs = train(model, num_epochs=max_epochs)
```

Then it triggered an error:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-46e63dbcb4bc> in <module>()
     52 model = Autoencoder()
     53 max_epochs = 20
---> 54 outputs = train(model, num_epochs=max_epochs)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2822     if size_average is not None or reduce is not None:
   2823         reduction = _Reduction.legacy_get_string(size_average, reduce)
-> 2824     return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2825 
   2826 

RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 4
```

My editable file on github is here: https://github.com/Suppersine/summercourse/blob/main/Hw7_2.ipynb
And here on colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1holj3La_bAA_W8DJRbPOsWp4ihZHImQk?usp=sharing
My dataset folder name is "pca_poker_data": https://github.com/Suppersine/summercourse/tree/main/pca_poker_data

you may download them to run, debug and troubleshoot my code. Thanks for helping me T_T _/_

Comment: You're going to need to do a bit more work to get help on SE. It's your responsibility to pull out the relevant pieces of code so that users intending to help have all relevant information WITHOUT visiting other links or downloading code.

Comment: In this case, it is quite obvious that your dataset is loading 4D data examples rather than 3D data examples which are expected by the `nn.Conv2D` layers in your network. So at least the dataset code should be posted

Comment: What does your input data look like ? What is it's shape ?

Comment: It seems that you need my full code but I have given you the dataset link, Alright I'll edit my post once more.